# Shrink an image to 1/4 of its original size.

Tags: java, eclipse, image, pixel

I am a programming newbie. I am asked to shrink an image to 1/4 its original size. And tutor told me I can replace 4 pixel with one pixel, so as to make it 1/4. How Can I do replacing work in java. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.  Homework is fine, but simply asking for code will generate hostile responses.  Make some attempts, and come back when you have specific questions, demonstrating the code you have tried

Comment: Thank you Jonesy. This is just a part of my task I am doing now, and I wasn't too sure whether it is able to post it here. I will post more specifically next time :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to programming then this is absolutely a lesson you should not be undertaking because it involves file IO, loops, data structures, and math.  None of these are relevant to the basics you should be learning now.

The basic algorithm would be that you read the pixels in the image into a matrix, and every 2x2 square of pixels could be replaces by one pixel by averaging the colors.

I am not going to give you a full answer because it would involve lots of API lookups to create a fully functional application to do this.  There would be a lot of code you probably wouldn't even understand if I showed it to you.

If this is for school, you are either far behind in your studies, or else your teacher is giving an unecessarily complex early assignment. Regardless of where this is coming from, you need to ask for a simpler assignment.

Either way, I recommend you take a step back and solve some simpler problems first so that you understand the components necessary to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Charles. I don't really think I am behind my study and the question I posted is just a small task of my course. The task provider does give us the those API, which we haven't learnt yet.And I am sure whether it is able to post those stuffs here. So I gotta study harder. Anyway, thanks!